# Spark how to partition data frame based on Year and Month

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to partition data frame by Year/Month/Day. I would also like to remove any empty partitions and save the output on my local machine under folders like Year/Month/Day.

I have tried the following but it still creates 200 odd partitions.

```
val sqldf = spark.sql("SELECT year(EventDate) AS Year_EventDate, month(EventDate) as Month_EventDate FROM table CLUSTER BY Year_EventDate,Month_EventDate")


sqldf.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").save(destinationFolder)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get 200 (I guess exactly?) partitions is because this is the default level of parallelism for a task in Spark. Depending on how big your data is, you can coalesce this down to fewer partitions if required.

```
saldf.coalesce(10)
```

To write to the folders that you want, you should first repartition the data into the folders you like, and then pass the hint to the writer

```
sqldf.repartition($"year", $"month", $"day").write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("year", "month", "day").save(destinationFolder)
```

making sure that columns year, month, day are whatever names you want to give them, and are columns in your data.